# How to and where to run .dn file

Tags: fonts, languages, indic

After saving the devanagari file with extension example.dn how and in which file I executive it to made example.tex file?

Comment: Why do you want to typeset devanagari like this instead of using lualatex and unicode?

Comment: Before the Unicode and XeLaTeX, there was Devanagari for TeX package, where you type a file with .dn extension, in English using  a Velthuis scheme, and then run the preprocessor "devnag" to conver the input to a .tex file, which you can LaTeX.

Comment: With Unicode, there is no necessity for dn files or devnag pre-processor.  One can directly type sanskrit in Unicode and run xelatex to generate the pdf file.

Comment: When I directly using devanagari alphabet then I getting makecmds.sty error?. In both case I getting error. However I think both should work well.